# Migrating cakephp application to django

Tags: django, cakephp

I have a cakephp application that has a users database and currently has approximately 50 users.

I was wondering what would be the best way to migrate the application to django without affecting the users.

I am concerned because the passwords are all encrypted of course, and most probably the encryption will not be the same in django.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to create the users with random passwords in your new application, then when switching send them an invitation with a login link. Take a look at this app: https://github.com/fajran/django-loginurl
Then ask the users to choose a password when they login the first time.

Second way, not so nice - but if you don't want to ask for the password again and you don't have a way to decrypt the existing one:
Modify your existing application in a way that it sends the username and password (taken from the existing login form - so you have it in cleartext) to the new backend. Then pull the profile from the legacy-app to the new one and create/migrate the user-profile.